# implicit TableHelper with 2.12.1?

Tags: phantom-dsl

Am I completely missing something? Trying to build the absolute most basic project with phantom is causing this error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter helper: com.outworkers.phantom.macros.TableHelper[models.Accounts,models.Account]
```

build.sbt is using version 2.12.1.

Account.scala is this:

```
package models
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._

case class Account(username: String)

abstract class Accounts extends Table[Accounts, Account] with RootConnector {
  object username extends StringColumn with PrimaryKey
}
```

I thought I was following the quickstart documentation, but I cannot get this to compile at all. Meanwhile, the Play-Cassandra project compiles just fine.

Comment: Found the problem. Using "with PrimaryKey" causes the issue. Changing this to "with PartitionKey" removes the error. (Maybe a better error message is needed here?)

Comment: The white box macro lib that should issue these warnings, as they are there, fails to do so properly, which sadly leaves us slightly powerless in most scenarios, though we are genuinely considering to use println..

Answer (score 6):

Writing here for future Googlers, this is because your schema does not define a `PartitionKey`, which is a requirement. The compiler should issue a warning when the macro is summoned.

```
package models
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._

case class Account(username: String)

abstract class Accounts extends Table[Accounts, Account] {
  object username extends StringColumn with PartitionKey
}
```

On a side note, extending `Table` already brings in `RootConnector`, so you do not need to explicitly extend it again, as it was the case in older versions of phantom using `CassandraTable` instead of `Table`.